# Subset data between specific points in R

Tags: r, subset

I am trying to subset some data in R between specific points. Specifically, I am looking to only return data after the minimum value and before the maximum value. My data set is similar to what is below. So, I'm trying to subset points data after point 8 and before data point 20.

```
   x1
1. 4
2. 4
3. 5
4. 5
5. 5
6. 4
7. 3
8. 0
9. 1
10. 2
11. 2
12. 3
13. 3
14. 4
15. 5
16. 6
17. 6
18. 7
19. 8
20. 6
21. 4
22. 2
```

So the expected output would be

```
8. 0
9. 1
10. 2
11. 2
12. 3
13. 3
14. 4
15. 5
16. 6
17. 6
18. 7
19. 8
```

I have tried

```
min <- min(x1)
max <- max(x1)
newdata <- subset(x1,x1<max|x1>min)
```

This returns the exact same data set. Which makes sense because all values are above the minimum or below the maximum. But is there a way to get the data specifically from the minimum to the maximum and exclude the data before the minimum and after the maximum? Thanks

Comment: `if(which.min(z) < which.max(z)) z[which.min(z) : which.max(z)] else z[which.max(z) : which.min(z)]` or if the order does not matter just `z[which.min(z) : which.max(z)]` assuming z is the column (vector) of interest

Comment: Can you please provide an example of the expected output?

Comment: Just did. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

ycw´s solution is clearly more elegant, but I´ll give you mine

```
cdata<-as.data.frame(c(4,4,5,5,5,5,4,3,0,1,2,2,3,3,4,5,6,6,7,8,6,4,2))
min <- min(cdata)
max <- max(cdata)
rowmax<- max(which(cdata == max))
rowmin<- min(which(cdata == min))

if (rowmax>rowmin){
  cdata<-cdata[rowmin:rowmax,, drop=FALSE]
} else{cdata<-cdata[rowmax:rowmin,, drop=FALSE]}
```

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately, someone did not like my answer and gave me a downvote. Nevermind, I will keep my answer here to see if this is helpful for the OP. Nice talking to you and I hope you the best.